# update -sql -query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update the table(`emp`) in MySql. Is there any way to write the following 3 queries as one?

```
update emp set name=?,sal=? where id=?;
update emp set name=? where id=?;
update emp set sal=? where id=?;
```

any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, if you updating the same `Id` you can use the first `update` and drop 2 others.

Comment: is that the same id in your where clause if so then you can drop your two update query as per above comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for a way where it may be possible. But I haven't found any. One solution is INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, in which case you should have a single insert query for all of your updates for a table, as below:

```
INSERT INTO emp (id, name, sal) 
VALUES
(34, 'Amjad', 25000),
(100, 'Irfan', 50000),
(643, 'Haris', 40000)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), sal = VALUES(sal);
```

but for this to work for you id column must be either a PK or unique key. so that if a record with the given id already exist, it will update the name and salary for the given record.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
update emp set name = case when id = ? then 'name' else name end, 
               sal = case when id = ? then 2000 else sal end 
where id in (?, ?, ?)
```

but I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use three queries, as they are more readable than offered approach.

Example:

```
update emp set name = case when id in (1, 2) then 'name' else name end,
               sal = case when id in (2, 3) then 2000 else sal end
where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

For `id = 2` both fields will be updated.

Comment: `set .. else null` why? I'd expected `else name` , `else sal`

Comment: @Serg I included comments to clarify that :)

Comment: `update emp set sal = 2000 where id in (2, 3)` will leave `sal` of  `id=1` as it is. You code will set it to `null`. Hardly this person will like it.

Comment: @Serg Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as you want to do an update on one or two columns for a given id.  If so:

```
update emp
    set name = coalesce(?, name),
        sal = coalesce(?, sal)
     where id = ?;
```

If you pass either of the first two parameters in as `NULL`, then the corresponding column values do not change.

Comment: She wants to have a single query for updating 3 records, instead of using 3 queries as she has shown.

Comment: @NoorAhmed . . . That is not how I interpret the question.

Comment: i want to update single record where i take user input as follows: 1)user might want to change name and salary for the given id 2) user might just want to change the name 3) user just want to change the salary 4)user might decide not to chane anything by giving N/A

Comment: Reason why i want to do this, i dont want to hit the db over and over for performance issues